# Failed to import the business network card in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am very new to this Hyperledger fabric. So trying to create fabric network using hyperledger composer. I have created bussiness network using composer. So afterwards I am trying to deploy business network to Hyperledger Fabric for a single organization following their official tutorial.
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org

So after creating PeerAdmin@fabric-network.card, when i am trying to import card to wallet getting error.

> Failed to import the business network card
>   keyword:    required
>   dataPath:   .peers['peer0.org1.example.com']
>   schemaPath: #/required
>   params: 
>     missingProperty: eventUrl
>   message:    should have required property 'eventUrl'
>
> Error: Errors found in the connection profile in the card

I have referred to this previously asked question
[Failed to import the business network card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451669/failed-to-import-the-business-network-card)
. But those things are not working. Can you please help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

[This Image link shows error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMryv.png)

Comment: as mentioned on Rocketchat - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693339/unable-to-import-card-in-hyperledger-composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my composer version and problem got resolved.Composer 0.19.13 has removed the mandatory requirement for eventUrl being present in the connection profile as it isn't required. Previous versions prior to this release will result in the error seen here if your connection profile doesn't contain the eventUrl entries. Composer documentation was updated when 0.19.13 was released to remove these redundant entries.